# Filter rows according to their frequency

Tags: r, tidyverse

Let's say we have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3),
  V2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3),
  V3 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  V4 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
)

> data
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1 ## 1st occurrence 
2     1     1     1     1 ## 2nd occurrence
3     1     1     1     1 ## 3rd occurrence
4     1     2     2     2 ## This row does not count while it occurs only once in the data
5     2     2     2     2 ## 1st occurrence
6     2     2     2     2 ## 2nd occurrence
7     1     1     3     3 ## This row does not count while it occurs only once in the data
8     3     3     3     3 ## This row does not count while it occurs only once in the data
```

We want to filter out rows which occur more often than a `threshold`; let's say threshold is set to 2 in our example. Additionally, values of the rows which don't reach the threshold are set to 0. Therefore, the result table should be:

```
> data_filtered
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1
3     1     1     1     1
4     0     0     0     0
5     2     2     2     2
6     2     2     2     2
7     0     0     0     0
8     0     0     0     0
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @amonk I add comments to the rows in the original dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 mutate(new = n()) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-new), funs(replace(., new < 2 , 0))) %>% 
 select(-new) %>% 
 ungroup()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 4
>      V1    V2    V3    V4
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     1     1     1
> 2     1     1     1     1
> 3     1     1     1     1
> 4     0     0     0     0
> 5     2     2     2     2
> 6     2     2     2     2
> 7     0     0     0     0
> 8     0     0     0     0
> ```

Comment: dont think u need rowwise here

Comment: @mtoto I tried it without too and it fails. A more ideal route would be `map` functions from `purrr`

Comment: u can look at my deleted solution, it works w/o `map()` and `rowwise()`

Comment: @mtoto hmm... I thought I tried that and didnt get it. I didnt ungroup though before replace...could that be it?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

 data <- data.table(
  V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3),
  V2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3),
  V3 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  V4 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
)

data[,key:=apply(data,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ""))]#create a unique key per row

setkey(data,key)  #set the "key" (to be used later on) 

data<-merge(data,data[,.N,by=key])#create the frequency N and propagate the values to the initial table via merge
```

So for the moment:

```
>data
    key V1 V2 V3 V4 N
1: 1111  1  1  1  1 3
2: 1111  1  1  1  1 3
3: 1111  1  1  1  1 3 
4: 1133  1  1  3  3 1
5: 1222  1  2  2  2 1
6: 2222  2  2  2  2 2
7: 2222  2  2  2  2 2
8: 3333  3  3  3  3 1

 data[,key:=NULL]#drop the key
```

You can now filter entire rows based on `N`, via:

```
data[N<=2,c("V1","V2","V3","V4"):=0]#set all columns to 0 if N is less or equal to 2
```

resulting in:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 N
1:  1  1  1  1 3
2:  1  1  1  1 3
3:  1  1  1  1 3
4:  0  0  0  0 1
5:  0  0  0  0 1
6:  2  2  2  2 2
7:  2  2  2  2 2
8:  0  0  0  0 1
```

Of course you can drop now `N` via `data[,N:=NULL]`